# How do you trim the size of a one-hot label and still keep it valid?

Tags: tensorflow

Given a batch of one-hot labels of length 10:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]  
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
```

...

```
I can trim it by 1 by using tf.slice():

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
```

but noticed that the first line is no longer a valid one-hot label (one of the column has to be set to 1).  How do I make it valid like this:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]

 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
```

whereby if none of the columns is set to 1, the last place column in a one-hot label is set to 1.

Thank you.

EDIT: I guess I should clarify to make it more concrete.  Let's say that I'm using the one-hot label from MNIST.  And I decided that instead of 10 digits, I'm using 9 digits only and I want to label everything from 0-8 instead of 0-9.  And I want all the 9-label to be converted into 6-label.
So, I want to reduce the shape of the one-hot from 10 to 9.  And fix the labels corresponding to this change.

For example: 
if the original encoding is: (5, 0, 9) it should now change to (5, 0, 6).
with [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.] becomes [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]

Comment: ...so you want to throw away a class? You'll either have to merge two classes together and assign the same one-hot code to both, or trow away all the samples of the class you're excluding

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
# Trim your one_hot in a tensor trimmed
exists = tf.reduce_sum(trimmed, axis=1)
zeros = tf.zeros_like(trimmed[:,:-1])
ones = tf.ones_like(trimmed[:,0:1])
zeros_ones = tf.concat((zeros,ones), axis=1)
final = tf.where(exists>1, trimmed, zeros_ones)
```

For example:

```
trimmed = [[0,0,1], [0,0,0], [1,0,0]]
exists = [1,0,1]
zeros_ones = [[0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,1]]
final = [[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[1,0,0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
data = tf.constant([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
                   [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

just use:

```
data[:, -2] += data[:, -1]
```

before applying `tf.slice()`.
Since those are all one hot vectors this single line will be enough.